# How to use the 'for loop' function and find numbers divisible by 7, python?

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers, and am trying to find all the numbers that are divisible by 2. So I found the 2 correct numbers, but in my output I get . Can anyone help me to get rid of that zero, since it's not in the list?

Here is my code:

```
k = [1, 610, 5, 3, 4884, 455, 555, 555, 555 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711]

divisible_by_2 = 0
for i in l:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        divisible_by_7 = divisible_by_7, i
    print("divisible_by_7:", i)

divisible_by_2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an list instead of tuples:

```
divisible_by_7 = []

for i in l:
    if (i % 7 == 0):
        divisible_by_7.append(i)
```

Comment: That's a list, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to add all the number7 divisibles in a list.
This part of your code is wrong as it will replace 0 with 0

```py
divisible_by_7 = 0
divisible_by_7 = divisible_by_7, i
```

You can do this

```py
l = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711]

divisible_by_7 = []

for i in l:
    if (i%7==0):
        divisible_by_7.append(i)
print(divisible_by_7)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Can you explain what was wrong in my code and how I can improve it for the next time?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is creating a nested tuple. In python, the expression `x, y` creates a tuple `(x, y)`, regardless of the parentheses. If you wanted to append to a tuple, the thing you append has to be a tuple too, like this:

```
divisible_by_7 += (i,)
```

You can always start with an empty tuple:

```
divisible_by_7 = ()
```

However, tuples are not very good for appending new items. They are immutable, so the entire tuple is reallocated and a new object is created every time, without amortization. Lists, on the other hand, can be modified in-place. The underlying buffer will still have to change, but the expansion is transparent to the user, and amortized when you have many additions one after another.

```
divisible_by_7 = []
for i in ...:
    if ...:
        divisible_by_7.append(i)
```

Expressions of this form (a single append in a `for` loop, with or without an `if`) fit well into the list comprehensions in python. A comprehension would have the following format:

```
divisible_by_7 = [i for i in ... if ...]
```

In your specific case:

```
divisible_by_7 = [i for i in l if not i % 7]
```

In this case, the condition `not i % 7` is equivalent to `i % 7 == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

While not using a `for` loop, an alternative approach to this type of problem is to use the built-in function [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter). You give it an iterable (like your list `l`) and a function that returns `True` for the elements that you want in the result.

```py
l = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711]

divisible_by_7 = list(filter(lambda i: i % 7 == 0, l))
```

Comment: Seems like a bit of overkill, but it definitely works

Comment: While it may be unfamiliar to those more used to for-loops, learning functional programming approaches with `filter`, `map`, and `reduce` may lead to more readable code in more complex examples, in my opinion. At the end of the day, for-loops, list comprehensions, and `map`/`filter` *usually* accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Totally agree. And comprehensions are the gray area between them.